# How do I explore the Black Sea Coast between Georgia and Istanbul?

Tags: cruising, istanbul, tbilisi, black-sea, batumi

I will be travelling to Georgia (Tbilisi) in June, and then want to go to Istanbul.

I would love to see some places along the Black Sea Coast along the way from Tbilisi - can someone please help me?

I have some questions...

1. How long is the bus ride from Tbilisi to Batumi? Is this the quickest method? At what time do they depart from Tbilisi?
2. Are there cruises/ferries from Batumi to Istanbul, and will they stop at various cities so passengers can explore and sight see?
3. If bus is the only option to travel from Batumi to Istanbul, how frequent are they? Will i be able to 'hop-on' and 'hop off' at various places on the way?
4. What about hiring a driver/guide?

Any suggestions/recommendations welcome,

much appreciated...

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to take a bus from Tbilisi to Batumi, and then cruise from there to Istanbul, is that right?  And presumably you want to consider a driver to make the land route to Istanbul? Or just the Batumi leg?  Please clarify, at the moment your question is attracting close votes as 'unclear what you are asking'.  Thanks